# Receiving error No base file for markup://c:DesignLwcDemo while deploying this to org

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx, error, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I am getting error
No base file for markup://c:DesignLwcDemo  while deploying this to org

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Design Attribute" icon-name="custom:custom5">
    {greeting}
    {heading}
</lightning-card>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
<target> Lightning__AppPage</target>
<target>Lightning__RecordPage</target>
<target>LightningCommunity__Page</target>
<target>LightningCommunity__Deafault</target>
<target>Lightning__HomePage</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage,Lightning__HomePage">
   <property name="greeting" type="String"></property>
   </targetConfig>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
    <property name="heading" type="String"> </property>
    <objects>
        <object>Account</object>
        <object>Contact</object>
        </objects>
   </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
```

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

 export default class DesignLwcDemo extends LightningElement {
 @api greeting;
 @api heading;

}
```

Comment: Not sure but have faced it. Can you please try deploying the component as a whole. If you're in vs code, do `ctrl + shift + e` go the parent folder `DesignLwcDemo` right click & `Deploy Source to org` & it should work.

Comment: it works thank you @SachinHooda